# Can the impressions created through what you say, be used to safeguard yourself from manipulation at workplace?

Tags: communication, colleagues, ethics, company-culture, pressure

I am writing this to get help on identifying some behaviours of people at workplace and develop my skills. I am a bit introverted and recently I came across a work place with a lot of toxic co-workers as well as superiors who do gossiping, backbiting and even undermining a lot. So I found it difficult with my introverted nature to deal as well.

When I was very new there, I tried to be with two other girls, 2 and 3 years younger than me, respectively. So that I have company, I mean.

One day, when we were having tea, the girl A said, "I am the eldest in the family, and I don't like to get controlled. I am the one who is bossing my brother even". By the tone and implications, the idea implied to me was that she feared that I might perhaps try to start handle them and become the leader among the 3 of us. And hence she tried to build a protective wall for her, by saying like this.

She anyway try to handle the girl B. Didn't try to do so to me that much, probably because I'm older than them. But she does backbiting.

Such an idea didn't even cross my mind, until she mentioned. I also, don't like to get handled, but I'm bit more peaceful than A so I don't try to handle anyone either. But I myself also don't like to get handled. In such a case, should I also be saying something like A did, to the new people I meet?

Is that a common way to protect yourself against people who try to manipulate you?

And there's another aspect. It was good because I'm a peaceful person, but if she said that to someone who is more toxic, they would have started to do the handling just because she doesn't like it right? That's also possible, isn't it?

Are there behaviours, body language and comments that we can really use to safeguard ourselves from getting manipulated?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What country/culture is this?

Comment: It's an asian country. Eventhough my name is english like, I'm a native here. A developing country. @DanielR.Collins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the tone and implications, the idea implied to me was that she feared that I might perhaps try to start handle them and become the leader among the 3 of us. And hence she tried to build a protective wall for her, by saying like this.

With all due respect, I feel that you are confusing things and are starting from an assumption that perhaps is not true.

Don't overthink it. Who knows, perhaps she was only sharing an anecdote, that doesn't imply she "fears" you will become "the leader" (leader as in? your friend group?). To be honest, this sounds a bit childish.

I suggest you focus on your job and keep it professional. There is no need to "show your claws" to people so they don't "handle" you. You are all in the same boat, perhaps reporting to the same person, so you should work as a team and leave the personal aspects out of it.

> I am a bit introverted and recently I came across a work place with a lot of toxic co-workers as well as superiors who do gossiping, backbiting and even undermining a lot. So I found it difficult with my introverted nature to deal as well.

Regardless of the advice given before, this is a red flag to me.

If you are not comfortable with the environment and have experienced that a lot of the people there are toxic then perhaps you should think if you really want to be there.

Comment: Thank you @DarkCygnus I know it's childish. I myself was surprised by those behaviours. But they form cliques and a person in the clique kind of try to act like a leader, informally. When I don't get too attached to be under a particular clique and follow exactly what that leader says, they try to look for chances to corner/attack me. That's why I'm trying to figure out whether I have a way to imply that

Comment: "I don't want to be in a clique, I have enough capacity to be the leader of my own work, and I'm harmless and won't try to lead them either and also anytime, I'll be a friend even though I keep my independence". Forming a peaceful but strong attitude. There are some who are able to maintain such independence. But I don't know how they do that. That's why I want to figure out. I've resigned from this place, still a bit of more days to go until my one month completes.

Comment: But I need to find a way to save myself from such situations in the future, because I've observed that a lot of people here have such behaviours. As the person who is being subjected to the situations, I can tell that that's how they behaved - not an assumption or a confusion, but it's difficult to explain it in words @DarkCygnus I think that's why it's even more dangerous to be subjected to such a situation. Please kindly advise on this too if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mary I think that you'll spare yourself from situations like this in the future by landing a job whose company's culture isn't as the one you just experienced (cliques, and "leaders of cliques" and gossip)... To put it in another perspective, why would it be a problem if you "became" the "leader" of ... this clique? Nothing. For this coworker perhaps it seems to be a problem, but that's *their* problem... This seems to suggest that (besides form the environment) this person is also a bit toxic and someone you may want to think if it's worth to continue hanging so often

Comment: and good luck with your new job :) I hope you found a place with better environment

Comment: Yes, I know, it's pretty childish to think about such leaders. In this country there has been a trend in schools, that teachers had been saying things like "You should be very forward, have leadership skills, be very outgoing, have a big mouth etc. else, you won't be able to survive in your workplaces in the future". When they said this, myself for instance took it as a good comment but I didn't try to activate it exactly like as if said in the book.

Comment: I mean I thought we just need to be humble and honest in the work environment too, in a practical sense. But many others tried to practice these and showed off that they are strong by cutting off another even. This has been happening in a lot of communities in here, I think it's unrefined behaviour, but I think now, that these things I observe at the workplaces are a result of such guidances during the childhood as well. So in many places this behaviour is there, it's a little bit too high here I think because of the presence of many highly forward characters, as they say.

Comment: I've compared by observation of behaving as such leaders, with some others too, they also agree that there is such a behaviour. I don't know how exactly to face this situation. Their final motive is that, I think, when they keep behaving like such a leader and so on, if there's going to be a promotion, they expect that they will automatically get the first chance instead of another in the clique. And thanks a lot for all your well wishes @DarkCygnus :) :)

Comment: @Mary interesting thoughts and reflection. Seems like a cultural thing and something that is deeply rooted in your society. To put it more negatively: something you can't change :/

Comment: Yeah, @DarkCygnus you've said it exactly. And true, I can't change it...But I also don't know how to adapt to face it still..

Comment: @Mary it's a matter of "toughing up", and accepting certain things (as in realizing that people like these can be found anywhere). Life is not perfect and the professional life is even farther away from being perfect. The sooner you realize that, the sooner you'll stop worrying about these details and be able to really focus on improving your career.